# Exception while executing LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, exception

i am developing this in ASP.NET MVC2

Getting exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
  Source="Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly"
  StackTrace:
       at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , TrusteeMaster )
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at LexEyeSystem.Controllers.TrusteeMasterController.JsonContractCollection(Int32 page, Int32 rows, String sidx, String sord) in D:\ParallelMinds\Projects\LexEye\Controllers\TrusteeMasterController.cs:line 560
       at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

I am trying to show jqgrid, for that purpose I have to write this JSON returning action, which contains my this Linq query. Same query running properly on other pages :

```
var jsonData = new 
{ 
    total = totalPages, 
    page = page, 
    records = totalRecords, 
    rows = ( 
          from s in sortedList 
          select new 
          { 
              cell = new string[] {                         
                "TrustContract/Edit/"+ s.TrusteeId.ToString(),                           
                s.FullName,
                s.OtherName.ToString(),
                s.FatherName,
                s.TrusteeGender,
                s.ResidentialAddress, 
                s.CommunicationAddress,
                s.Occupation,
                s.Nationality,
                s.DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString(),
                s.PlaceOfBirth,
                s.TelephoneNumber,
                s.FacsimileNumber,
                s.MobileNumbers,
                s.EmailId,
                s.ElectionIdCardNumber,
                s.PANCardNumber,
                s.TaxRegistrationNumber,
                s.Qualification,
                s.ExperienceInYears.ToString(),
                s.Resume.ToString(), 
                "DisclousureInterestDetails/Index/"+ s.TrusteeId.ToString(),//+"?trusteeId="+s.TrusteeId.ToString(), 
                "ForeignDetail/Create/"+ s.TrusteeId.ToString(),
                "InterestedOtherCompanyInformation/Index/"+ s.TrusteeId.ToString(), 
                "RelativesDetails/Index/"+ s.TrusteeId.ToString() 

            }
          }).ToArray()
};
```

But why it should not running here?

**Edit:** LINQ query to get sortedList:

```
var sortedList = objTrusteeMasterList
                    .AsQueryable()
                    .OrderBy(orderBy) // Uses System.Linq.Dynamic library for sorting
                    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: The issue is probably with your `sortedlist` - what's the LINQ query you are using for that?

Comment: Please see the edited question I have given Linq query . But it is giving proper results. It is not generating any exception As per i debugged. Is any way to debut the code that I have given (Linq) statement by statement ?

Comment: Can you spend some time cleaning up your code - there are `<br/>` at the end of each line, and the first line isn't 4 characters indented so its not coming up as code but rather plain text.  Makes it hard to read, and thus hard for us to answer.

Comment: I think it is looking well. no need to clean it .I already spend my time over this question much to format it. I have manually put <br /> there so it looks well . anyway I got answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the sortedList in you `from s in sorteList` is NULL or not.

I think the exception is thrown when LINQ calls `MoveNext` method on `sortedList`.

Comment: Hi Unmesh, Thanks for reply. it's done. it was not a problem of sorted list or its containing object actually ! i had some null values in db. so while getting value in select statement like "s.FullName.ToString()" here should be   Convert.ToString(s.FullName). and it is working perfect. but you preserve +1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If I call to the ToArray() method after

```
from s in sortedList 
          select new ...
```

I also got an exception. The problem were the calls to **ToString()**. If the element was null it would fail.